# AlFresco Manual Setup

Tags: mysql, alfresco, windows-server-2012, manual

I would like to set up AlFresco on a hosted Windows 2012 server. I have MySQL db available.

Could anyone provide pointers or an outline procedure please.

Thanks
I.

Comment: Which version of Alfresco are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You should look to official [Alfresco documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/tasks/simpleinstall-community-win.html) about installing.
This step-by-step guide is good for Community edition .

In general after downloading installation files you should only follow the wizards.

If you need to perform a manual installation you should take a look to [various distributions](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/download-community.html) containing all the files you may need.

For Enterprise edition you should follow the procedures about [Installing Alfresco Enterprise](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/ch-install.html) which include:

- Software requirements
- Production environment checklist
- Alfresco installation files
- Installing Alfresco on Tomcat
- Removing unused applications
- Installing an Alfresco Module Package
- Language support